# why cant i add photos in my python turtle program

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

im using

```
    wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders\playerspaceinvaders.gif"))
```

but its not working. its saying

> "  File "C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders\Space Invaders.py", line 11
>       wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser("C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders\playerspaceinvaders.gif"))
>                                      ^
>   SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
>   [Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
>   [shell_cmd: python -u "C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders\Space Invaders.py"]
>   [dir: C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders]
>   [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Python3.8.1\Scripts;C:\sqlite3;C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32]"

i imported turtle and os please help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please read the guide on [ask] and post a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

The path you're providing has escape characters (`\`) in it, and so it is trying to butcher your string. As you want to use your string as-is, use a raw string by prefixing it with an `r`: `wn.addshape(os.path.expanduser(r"C:\Users\Dianna Jackson\Desktop\space invaders\playerspaceinvaders.gif"))`

Comment: also can skip ```os.path.expanduser``` since it isn't applicable as no ~ is present.

Comment: and now its still giving off an error idk whats going on

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: @Jonah.Jackson can you provide the new Traceback, or open a new question for your new issue if not yet resolved / cannot be resolved through investigation?

Comment: @Oliver.R it works fine now had to change some stuff

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the image file in the same folder in your computer as you are saving the code. If you are already doing this, then I'm afraid I'm not sure what's wrong.